# Netbeans generated JAX-WS client does not work if Axis2 library is present

Tags: java, jax-ws, apache-axis

I generated a JAX-WS web service client using Netbeans, every thing works fine except if i add Axis2 library to the project the UsernameToken is removed from the soap header and the soap message looks slightly different. I'm quite new to Java web services so i would really like to understand what is going on and how to solve this. The reason why i need to have the Axis2 library is that I'm adding a client to an large project that has many Axis2 clients.

Generated SOAP when Axis2 library is present:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" />
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:AddOrUpdate xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.DataTransferObjects" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.ServiceUtils">
    <ns2:employee />
    </ns2:AddOrUpdate>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Generated SOAP without Axis2 library:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>password1</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</S:Header>
<S:Body>
<AddOrUpdate xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.DataTransferObjects" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.ServiceUtils" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <employee/>
</AddOrUpdate>
</S:Body>
```